# Inner join or foreach to get final data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Which kind of query is correct to use? I need to get an array of this data. I'm talking about benchmark and standards of PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN users_groups AS ug ON (u.id = ug.user_id)";
$array = $sql->fetchAll();
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
foreach($sql as $value) {
    $array[] = $users_group = "SELECT * FROM users_groups WHERE user_id = $value[id]";
}
return $array;
```

Comment: Do as much as possible in mysql (think performance). Do as little as possible in php (a.k.a. non-performance)

Comment: either will be [producing an array for you. if you don't need to process the data as you fetch, then might as well use fetchAll().

Answer (score 0):

The first query is much better from a performance perspective since the second may result in n +1 queries where n is the number of users.  Generally it is best to avoid round trips to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In case of performance, I always go with your first query because it is always better to get required data with all conditions applied in query itself, Instead of making it in PHP with loop and multiple times hitting mysql server will also cause delay in performance

You can check the performance and execution timing using `microtime()`

For eg:-

```
$start_time = microtime(true);

// your code

$end_time = microtime(true);

$exe_time = $end_time-start_time;

echo "execution time: ".$exe_time;
```